# Pow server: serving local rails app via myapp.dev.com domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rack-pow

Pow server is working fine with .dev domains on my local machine (OS X Lion). So myapp.dev is all good.

I now would like to make it serve myapp.dev.com (and myapp.dev.fr, and myapp.dev.XX) so myapp will serve the localized version, which is internally determined via the top-level-domain requesting: .com for english, fr for french ... and so on.

what i did so far: setting .powconfig to

```
export POW_DOMAINS=dev,dev.com,dev.fr
export POW_EXT_DOMAINS=dev.com,dev.fr
```

and then, of course, un- and reinstalling pow.

what i get so far when calling myapp.dev.com is just the regular apache view. pow doesnt serve my request... instead it sends it to apache and apache shows just all my folders in my server root...

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

...simple as that...

1. follow  this wiki https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Running-Pow-with-Apache (step 3 is the important one)
2. then of course create/modify .powconfig to contain this line

   ```
   export POW_DOMAINS=dev,dev.com,dev.fr
   ```
3. finally make pow "aware" of this new setup via de-  and reinstalling it

   ```
   curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
   curl get.pow.cx | sh
   ```

   and as a last step: restart apache

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```